# Shortcut to map an array to exactly the same array

Tags: ruby

Is there some way to use syntax similar to:

```
array.map(&:some_method)
```

to map elements to themselves, so that it would be equivalent to the following?

```
array.map{ |x| x }
```

So something like this (pseudocode):

```
array.map(&:self)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I am assessing elements in array to multiple conditions with 'delete_if' & 'keep_if' to get the state but I don't want original array to change. But clone worked just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you could use the `clone` method [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-clone). i.e. `array.clone`

Comment: @JakubZak After seeing your comment on the question, you may not need to use clone. If you use reject and select instead of delete_if and keep_if (respectively) they will return a new array with only the items you want.

Comment: Ended up doing exactly that, did clone first and then replaced it with select and reject. Thank you for comment though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do this:

```
array.map(&:itself)
```

Comment: You can't: ``map': undefined method `itself' for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @JakubZak Cannot be reproduced. If you are using an old Ruby, you should specifically mention so in the question.

Comment: `require "pp"`

     `a = ["1","2","3","4","5"]`
     `b = a.map(&:itself).keep_if { |n| n == "4"}`

     `pp a`
     `pp b`

     `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`
     `b = a.map(&:itself).keep_if { |n| n == 4}`

     `pp a`
     `pp b`
`

Answer (score 0):

If you have some strings array, you can do

```
pry(main)> a.map{|x| eval x}
=> [4]
```

But `eval` is not a string method. In this case you'll need put a var in `map`.

also, i think this code will speak better than me

```
2.3.0 :001 > a=[]
 => [] 
2.3.0 :002 > b=def foo
2.3.0 :003?>   2+2
2.3.0 :004?>   end
 => :foo 
2.3.0 :005 > a<<b
 => [:foo] 
2.3.0 :006 > a.map{&:send}
SyntaxError: (irb):6: syntax error, unexpected &
a.map{&:send}
       ^
        from /home/kvokka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.3.0 :007 > a.map{|x| send x}
 => [4]
```